# Predicate as the subject of another triple

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, owl, rdfs

Lets says I have a RDF triple store that has

```
:Person1 :hasLocation :Location1.
```

Am I allowed to create other triples with :hasLocation as subject/object? (examples below):

```
:hasLocation rdf:Type :LocationPredicates.
:hasLocation rdfs:label "someLabel".
:hasLocation rdfs:comment "someComment".
:hasLocation :someProperty :otherObject
```

Comment: If it's just about RDF data, yes sure. If it's OWL, also yes - it's called punning.

Comment: By the way, you have a typo in `rdf:Type`, it's case sensitive, thus, it must be `rdf:type`.

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful.

Comment: Note that this is all true in RDF but, since you also tagged OWL, :someProperty needs to be an annotation property or you will have effectively a property and an individual with the same IRI. This is OK but often surprising (it is punning, as mentioned already).